# Zeppelin + Spark 1.6.1 Connection Refused

Tags: connection, apache-zeppelin

Setup: `zeppelin-0.6.0-dse-5.0.0-5.0.1 + Spark 1.6.1`

connection issue while running a notebook containing a single statement %spark.

> Error Trace: INFO [2017-11-26 09:37:27,981] ({pool-1-thread-2}
>   RemoteInterpreterProcess.java[reference]:143) - Run interpreter
>   process [/data/zeppelin-0.6.0/bin/interpreter.sh, -d,
>   /data/zeppelin-0.6.0/interpreter/spark, -p, 34222, -l,
>   /data/zeppelin-0.6.0/local-repo/2CYEPSQ2N]  INFO [2017-11-26
>   09:37:28,009] ({Exec Default Executor}
>   RemoteInterpreterProcess.java[onProcessComplete]:276) - Interpreter
>   process exited 0 ERROR [2017-11-26 09:37:58,054] ({Thread-15}
>   RemoteScheduler.java[getStatus]:255) - Can't get status information
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: Requires editing: recommend formatting error message as <pre> or code.